# Extract environment variable at install time in msi (wxs)

Tags: wix, windows-installer

My idea is to extract the value of environment variable `ZEN_HOME` and assign it to variable `MyInstallDir` at install time, and if it is not set, then set the variable with some other value `ProgramFileFolder`.

The error i am facing is, wxs at compile time, is searching for the value, instead of install time.

How to make sure that the value is extracted at install time and not compile time?

```
<?if %ZEN_HOME% != "" ?>
    <?define MyInstallDir = %ZEN_HOME% ?>
<?else?>
    <?define MyInstallDir="ProgramFilesFolder" ?>
<?endif?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do will execute at compile time, as you correctly mentioned, during preprocessing. You can't leverage WiX variables at install time - it's totally WiX custom concept Windows Installer knows nothing about.

So, if I understand your intention correctly, you're going to set the installation directory of your application to some value of environment variable, if it's there on a target machine. Otherwise, fall back to a folder under Program Files.

You can approach it in the following way.
First, define the directory structure similar to this:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
   <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="MySetupProject">
         ...
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

This will serve as a fallback. Later, define a [set-a-property](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_setproperty.htm) custom action to set INSTALLLOCATION in case there's an environment variable defined:

```
<SetProperty Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[%ZEN_HOME]" After="CostFinalize">[%ZEN_HOME]</SetProperty>
```

You should schedule it after [CostFinalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368048.aspx) to be able to address directories as properties.

Comment: Ahh..thanks a lot. There is already an existing line in wxs at end: `<Custom Action="SetInstallationDirectory" After='CostFinalize' />` shall i remove it? I am pretty new to msi concepts, basically a Linux guy, but our product has a Linux and Windows version, that's why the trouble.

Comment: Or do you want me to add the `<SetProperty Id..` after the `<Custom Action="SetInstallationDirectory" After='CostFinalize' />` line?

Comment: Well, actually `<SetProperty>` element is just a shortcut for a pair of set-a-property custom action definition (`<CustomAction>` element) and its scheduling into the installation sequence (`<Custom>` element). I think you should find out what your existing custom action called `SetInstallationDirectory` does first, and later on either adjust it to the behavior you need, or add a new one if it's totally for other purpose. It's hard to understand without seeing the definition of `SetInstallationDirectory` custom action...

Comment: Ahh..i got it.     `<CustomAction Id="SetInstallationDirectory" 
        Directory="INSTALLATIONDIRECTORY"
        Value="[%ZEN_HOME]" />` so i appended the ZEN_HOME here to it. I hope that is what you were looking for to set, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Make sure it is scheduled properly - after CostFinalize, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Yes, it is: `<Custom Action="SetInstallationDirectory" After='CostFinalize' />` thanks a ton.

Comment: Hi, i am encountering a problem. when the env variable is not present, it is giving error while installation: Error2343. Internal error. Should the dir structure be present?

Comment: Add a condition for a custom action, so that it doesn't run if env variable is not there. Like this: `<Custom Action="..." After="...">[%ZEN_HOME]</Custom>`. I mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: I raised a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296004/msi-installation-fails-if-env-path-is-altered-or-deleted please help if you can

Comment: @YanSklyarenko - this was a really helpful answer and comment thread - I was able to solve one of my own problems using your answer, but I did notice that, using Wix v3.9.1208.0, that the brackets needed to be removed from the condition?  So:

     `After="...">%ZEN_HOME</Custom>`

This might be useful info for a future reader!